# background image not showing of Card View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles, android-cardview

I try to create a little round view in relative layout. but when i set image(.jpg) in card view then image is not showing.

```
                <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/View"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

What i want you can see in following image.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to create a round view that contains imageview. So first, set your image using ImageView and not the CardView itself.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/View"
      android:layout_width="25dp"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="12.5dp"
      android:layout_margin="2dp"
      android:elevation="2dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Normally, your imageview image would overlap your cardview, so to avoid that, just set your imageview **clipToOutline** to true programmatically in your activity.

```
imageView.clipToOutline = true
```

Comment: can i set radius on image view ? I just wanna to create right marked view like other views..

Comment: No need to set the radius on your imageview as you already provided radius in the parent cardview @AkashAttal

Comment: @AkashAttal Also, set the cardview corner radius to half of the height to achieve rounded view

Comment: i update my question. now can understand very well. i wish...

Comment: @AkashAttal Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes i try but its not work.. may be card view is not working in min size. like 25dp